# How to call a JavaScript function using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call JavaScript or jquery function using variable.

```
var fnName= "abc"; //how to use fnName as a function call where "abc" will be function name

function abc(){   //definition........ }
```

Comment: I think these answers might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Comment: Best way is to wrap these functions in an object and the `object[functionName]()`

Answer (score 4):

Define function globally.

**First Way**
Call as `window[functionName]()`.

```js
function abc() {
  alert('test');
}

var funcName = 'abc';

window[funcName]();
```

**Second Way** Add function to defined object.

```js
function parentFunc(name) {
  var childFuncs = {
    "abc": function() {
      alert("test");
    }
  }
  
  childFuncs[name]();
}

var funcName = 'abc';

parentFunc(funcName);
```

Comment: but it will not work inside any other funcion/nested scope, and may be changing the requirement to declare globally